# Google Cloud Speaker Diarization Not Working On Some Files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I'm running the google cloud speech-to-text API with diarization enabled, see example at the link below:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-voices#enabling_speaker_diarization_in_a_request

Note furthermore that I'm using this function to call the API:

```
def transcribe_audio(uri):
    print(f'transcribing {uri}...')
    client = speech.SpeechClient()
    audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(uri=uri)
    config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
        language_code='en-US',
        enable_speaker_diarization=True,
        diarization_speaker_count=2)
    response = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
    return list(response.result().results)
```

When parsing the output the speaker labels are supposed to appear in the last element of the result list. I've confirmed this with one audio file but when I try running it with other audio files, there are no speaker-labels in the result. In fact, when I've tried the API with other files the last result in the result list doesn't contain a transcript of the entire file, but merely a segment. **My question is why does this happen and how can I correct it?**

Note that my files are large (~ 1 GB) flac files that contain a few hours of audio. It's also important to note that they are all prepared with the same preprocessing script, and it's not clear in what way they could be different enough to get different results from the API (i.e. the fact that some get speaker labels and others don't).

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm getting the same issue, where speaker diarization comes and goes depending on video.

Comment: Hey Jack - I didn't unfortunately. I would be great to hear from you if you figure it out! Thanks.

Comment: Because it's a beta feature, make sure you're importing the beta library like this: const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech').v1p1beta1;